# How do I bind a ListBox to a list of objects from an XML file?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

Hello I am trying to parse a simple xml file containing a list of usernames and then bind the results to a listbox

The xml looks like this

```
<friends type = Array>
   <userId> xxxx </userId>
   <userId> yyyy </userId>
   <userId> zzzz </userId>
   <userId> wwww </userId>
         ...
   <userId> aaaa </userId>
</friends>
```

My parse code looks like this

> ```
> XDocument friendFeed = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(response.Content));
>                var friendsData = from query in friendFeed.Descendants("friends")
>                                   select new Friend
>                                   {
>                                     userId = (string)query.Element("userId"),
>                                     profileImage = imageurl + (string)query.Element("userId")  + "/avatar.png"
>                                   };
>
>                 friendListBox.ItemsSource = friendsData;
> ```

This works but only returns one user the very first one. Is there another way to parse/loop through this document then bind it to the listbox?

Hi guys, Thanks for the responses! I played around with the code and came up with a solution that works. Its in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses! I played around with the code and came up with a solution that works.

```
 XDocument friendFeed = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(response.Content));

                List<string> values = new List<string>();

                 foreach (XElement item in friendFeed.Descendants("userId"))
                 {

                      values.Add(item.Value);

                 }

                 var friends = from query in values
                               select new Friend
                               {
                                   userId = query,
                                   profileImage = imageurl + query + "/avatar.png"
                               };
                 friendListBox.ItemsSource = friends;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
var friend = Xmldoc.SelectNodes("/");  
foreach (XmlNode friend in friends )  
{    
   var userIds= person.ChildNodes;      
   foreach(XmlNode userId in userIds )     
   {       //get the userId   
   }  
}
```